# For what $x \in \mathbb{R}$ does the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n!x^{n}$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

For what $x \in \mathbb{R}$ does the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n!x^{n}$ converge?

How would you prove this? Does the ratio test apply?

Comment: "Does the ratio test apply?" : Try and you'll see !!! But Ratio test always works... like all other test. But it's not enough to determine all $x$ (you need to check what happen on the bound)

Comment: @Surb not in this case.

Comment: @quid: yes it does.

Comment: @Surb I meant that when the radius of convergence given by the ratio test is $0$ then there is no need to check anything "on the boundary." It's not quite clear what you assumed I was saying. As yeah the ratio test applies, as I said in my answer.

Comment: ........                                                        0                                             ........

Comment: Linking to a [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2171673).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the ratio test applies and yields that it converges for $x=0$ only.

Let me know if you need more details.